# RDP connection, where Windows stores passwords?

Tags: windows, rdp

I have a .rdp file with all my configurations but no **password** field. When I double click it, RDP opens my desktop correctly.

My question is: where Windows stores my rdp account password?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/296802/remoteapp-rdp-embed-creds

Comment: Where's the evidence that you have tried to find the answer for yourself?

Comment: I didn't asked to embed credentials but where windows stores them because in my RDP file there are no "password".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of two:

- SSO via NTLM/CredSSP - http://blog.powershell.no/2009/12/25/single-sign-on-to-remote-desktop-services/ if you're in a Active Directory domain
- You've selected to save the password previously, which stores the password in the Windows Credential Manager Store - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh994565(v=ws.10).aspx